# Reading from file keeps disregarding decimals in float

Tags: c++, file, stream, decimal

So I am having trouble with the following:

I save a variable in a config file (it saves exactly fine the whole float number) and when I read the variable from config file it disregards everything after the decimal of the float.

Example 5.1234 comes out as 5.0000. I must have made some silly mistake which I just cant spot myself so maybe someone with more knowledge can spot it. Thanks!

I have a struct for Options where I have some default values:

```
struct Options
{
  float b_aX = 4.50f;
   ...
    ...

  float* aX = &b_aX;
}
```

Then I try to read from the file where I have stored a new value for this variable:

```
ifstream file("c:\\bllaa.cfg");
string str;  

float cfg[100] = {};
int total_lines = 0;

    while (getline(file, str)) {
        cfg[total_lines] = std::stoi(str);
        total_lines++;
    }  
 
//Finally read the value from the file and it comes out ignoring the decimals!
 Options.aX[0] = cfg[0];
```

In file `ax` = 5.1234
After reading from file `ax` = 5.0000

Comment: The `i` in `stoi` stands for *integer*, use `stof` instead, the `f` stands for *float*.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem's cause:**
This line:

```
cfg[total_lines] = std::stoi(str);
```

is causing the floating point value to be converted to an integer, due to the usage of [**`stoi`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol.).

**The solution:**
Using [**`stof`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) instead will maintain the floating point value:

```
//----------------------vvvv------
cfg[total_lines] = std::stof(str);
```